# Strange message when running `python` or `pip` command "dyld[19439]: rebase opcodes terminated early at offset 1 of 9040

Tags: macos, python

I'm using OSX. When I'm running `python --version` or any other command which starts with the `python` or `pip`, I get this message

```
"dyld[19439]: rebase opcodes terminated early at offset 1 of 9040
```

I didn't find what that could be. I tried a few times to remove Python and install it again, but it didn't work.

Right now, I've added to my .zshrc the following:

```bash
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
alias python3=/usr/bin/python3
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip3
```

and looks like it works, but I have doubts about whether it's a good solution.

Important to note that provided fix doesn't fully resolve the issue. When I'm trying to run the nvim-dap-python the error log shows the following:

```
[ ERROR ] 2022-10-24T17:53:00Z+0300 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1164 ]    "stderr"    {
  args = { "-m", "debugpy.adapter" },
  command = "/Users/..../api/.venv/bin/python",
  type = "executable"
}   "dyld[20328]: rebase opcodes terminated early at offset 1 of 9040\n"
[ INFO ] 2022-10-24T17:53:00Z+0300 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1128 ] "Closed all handles"
[ INFO ] 2022-10-24T17:53:00Z+0300 ] ...nvim/site/pack/packer/start/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1131 ] "Process closed"    20328   false
```

When I run `which python` without aliases, I'm getting this:

```
/Users/<user>/.pyenv/shims/python
```

macOS Monterey (version12.6)
Processor 2,3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
Memory 16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4
Startup Disk Macintosh HD
Graphics Radeon Pro 560X 4 GB

I'm installing python using the `brew` command

Comment: You are using pyenv - also looks like running from nvim which does not look at aliases also probably looks for a different python environment. You need to state EXACTLY how you installed python and how you are using it. ALso which version of macOS and I suspect the type of CPU

Comment: I'm using venv, however, even when I run without any env, I get the error.

Comment: How exactkly are you running python - if as per your last line you are using an environment

Comment: Please don't add text as images - they aree difficult to read

Comment: "if as per your last line you are using an environment" - I've added nvim info because aliases don't fix my issue fully.
"How exactly are you running python" - I open terminal and running `python --version`

Comment: How EXACTLY did you install python? How did .pyenv get on your $PATH

Comment: I don't remember how EXACTLY .pyenv get on my path

Comment: That is the basic problem.

Comment: What do you mean by the basic problem?

Comment: How did the pyenv get on the PATH - it is not done by just installing python

Comment: ok, but still, I am unsure how it got on the PATH :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed all Python versions and all aliases.
After I also removed the pyenv using `brew` command.

After all these steps, I installed pyenv.

Using pyenv, I installed two python versions:

```bash
pyenv install 3.10.4
pyenv install 2.7.15
```

Finally, I set the python versions in the following way:

```bash
pyenv global 3.10.4 2.7.15
```

Seems that everything works now.